# Testing multiple landing pages simultaneously

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, marketing

Let's say we are wanting to test the conversion rate for multiple landing pages. To be safe, we must allocate 50% of our traffic to our current "champion" page. We then have 8 "challenger" pages we'd like to test.

Normally, for a simple comparison between two web pages, one might use an A/B test. For multiple pages, simultaneously, I would think an anova would be the correct route, but in our case, we will only have the conversion rates for each "group" (page) not a series of observations from which we'd derive in-group variation. Also, I'd think that the balance issues would be pretty significant given that the control group has a much bigger sample size.

Is there a right way to go about this?

Comment: What balance issues?  It sounds like there's more going on here than you describe.  Otherwise, in its most basic form, wouldn't you have a pair of counts for each of your nine pages (visitors and those who take some action), yielding a standard $2\times 9$ ANOVA table? What might be a little non-standard is the question you are asking of the data. You probably don't care about independence.  You only want to know whether at least one of the challenger groups has a higher rate than the control group.

Comment: thanks, does not ANOVA require a calculation of in group variation? Also, is it not a problem that one group will have a much larger sample size? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: The estimate of in-group variation is determined by the counts themselves.  There is no inherent problem with different group sizes: this is the standard situation.  A huge imbalance only leads to a relatively low power to detect differences, but does not invalidate the test.  You can perform this analysis using a GLM or a simple chi-squared test.